# wkhtmltopdf Table is starting from next page instead of breaking

Tags: pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, html-pdf

Table is starting from next page instead of breaking in the same page, It breaks properly if I reduce few rows or add few rows.

I have `break-inside: avoid;`  in parent container and in Table Row `break-inside: avoid; page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto;`

Web URL https://kaingaora-pricelist.co.nz/pdf-test/display

CSS Code looks like

```
.single-block * {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}

table tr, table .tr {
    break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-after: auto;
}
```

I am using `phpwkhtmltopdf 2.5`
command used  `wkhtmltopdf  https://kaingaora-pricelist.co.nz/pdf-test/display pdftest.pdf`

Below Image is Actual Output vs Expected Output, I would appreciate any help. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adjust Page Break Properties for Tables

```
.single-block * {
    page-break-inside: auto;
    break-inside: auto;
}

table, table tr, table .tr {
    page-break-inside: auto;
    break-inside: auto;
    page-break-after: auto;
}
```

Redefine the Parent Container's Properties If the .single-block class is the parent container You might need to adjust or remove the page-break-inside: avoid; and break-inside: avoid;